# Type Error of Array of Objects in ReactJS and has no data

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

Actually i have 2 questions. First when i try to setLesson i get

```
"Type 'Lesson | Lesson[]' is not assignable to type 'Lesson'.
  Type 'Lesson[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Lesson': name, note, hour, startDate, and 2 more."
```

error in parent component
This is my Parent comp.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Lesson } from './LessonType'
import NewLessonModal from './NewLesson';
function LessonList() {
    const [lessons, setLessons] = useState<Lesson[]>([]);
    const url = "https://localhost:7065/api/Lessons"
    const addLesson = (lesson: Lesson[]) => {
        setLessons([...lessons, lesson])
        console.log(lesson)
    }
}
    return (
        <div>
            <NewLessonModal addLesson={addLesson} />
        </div>
    )

}
```

and this is my child comp.

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import { Lesson } from './LessonType'
type Props = {
    addLesson(lessonData: Lesson[]): void
}
function NewLessonModal({ addLesson }: Props) {
    const [name, setname] = useState<string>("")
    const [notes, setnotes] = useState<string>("")
    const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState<string>("")
    const [endDate, setendDate] = useState<string>("")
    const [hour, sethour] = useState<number>(0)
    const [certificate, setcertificate] = useState<string>("")
    const [imagePath, setimagePath] = useState<string>("")
    const [lessonData, setLessonData] = useState<Lesson[]>([])

    const changeValue = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.name === "name") {
            setname(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "notes") {
            setnotes(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "startDate") {
            setstartDate(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "endDate") {
            setendDate(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "hour") {
            sethour(Number(event.target.value))
        }

    }
    const addNewLesson = () => {
        setLessonData([
            ...lessonData,
            { name: name, note: notes, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, hour: hour, certificate: certificate, imagePath: imagePath }
        ]);
        addLesson(lessonData)
    }
return ....
```

Lesson type file is

```
export interface Lesson{
   name:string,
   note:string,
   imagePath?:string,
   hour:number,
   startDate:string,
   endDate:string,
   certificate:string,
   id?:number,
   createdDate?:string 
}
```

I can't fix this type error and i tried to pass data to parent component. First array of object has no data. Second pass data process i got first data in parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `NewLessonModal` there is no need to have a extra `lesson` state. You can use all the other state to return 1 new lesson object. We can update the `Props` to have a single lesson in the callback instead of a array.

```js
type Props = {
  addLesson(lesson: Lesson): void;
};

function NewLessonModal({ addLesson }: Props) {
  const [name, setname] = useState<string>("");
  const [notes, setnotes] = useState<string>("");
  const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState<string>("");
  const [endDate, setendDate] = useState<string>("");
  const [hour, sethour] = useState<number>(0);
  const [certificate, setcertificate] = useState<string>("");
  const [imagePath, setimagePath] = useState<string>("");

  const changeValue = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.name === "name") {
      setname(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "notes") {
      setnotes(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "startDate") {
      setstartDate(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "endDate") {
      setendDate(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "hour") {
      sethour(Number(event.target.value));
    }
  };

  const addNewLesson = () => {
    // add a new object with all the properties
    addLesson({
      name: name,
      note: notes,
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate,
      hour: hour,
      certificate: certificate,
      imagePath: imagePath,
    });
  };

  return ();
}
```

Now in the `LessonList` we need to reflect these changes by updating the type of the callback.

```js
function LessonList() {
  const [lessons, setLessons] = useState<Lesson[]>([]);
  const url = "https://localhost:7065/api/Lessons";

  const addLesson = (lesson: Lesson) => {
    console.log(lesson);
    setLessons([...lessons, lesson]);
    // or
    // setLessons((prevLessons) => {
    //   return [...prevLessons, lesson];
    // });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NewLessonModal addLesson={addLesson} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also worth to mention, when doing this the `addLesson` function will not receive the updated `lessonData` from the lines above since React state updates are *kinda async*

```js
setLessonData([
  ...lessonData,
  {
    name: name,
    note: notes,
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    hour: hour,
    certificate: certificate,
    imagePath: imagePath,
  },
]);
addLesson(lessonData);
```